# Extend Walker Class for 2 checkbox taxonomy selection?

Tags: walker, terms

I am working on an add-content front end form (posts in this case).

I am able to display, and add, categories and taxonomies to posts correctly with the following:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <?php wp_terms_checklist( 0, array( 'taxonomy' => 'category', ) ); ?>
</div>    
<div class="checkbox">
    <?php wp_terms_checklist( 0, array( 'taxonomy' => 'city', ) ); ?>
</div>
```

**Update #1**, my first mistake was wrapping the `<li>`in a `<div class="checkbox">`. I have simply wrapped the WP terms function in a `<ul class="list-inline">`, but more can be done clearly.
[image: wp terms inline]

**Now the lists display as desired inline**, but question is still valid. How do I modify the `<li>` of the `Walker_Category_Checklist` for more than one taxonomy?

So far I've got (`functions.php`):

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/template.php' );

class Stdy_Custom_Tree_List extends Walker_Category_Checklist
{
    public $tree_type = 'category';

    public $db_fields = array ( 'parent' => 'parent', 'id' => 'term_id' );

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "<ul class='inline'>\n";
    }

    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</ul>\n";
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
        $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" . 
            '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . 
            '" type="checkbox" name="' . $name . '[]" id="in-' . $taxonomy . 
            '-' . $category->term_id . '"' . 
            checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'] ), true, false ) . 
            disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' . 
            esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name ) ) . '</label>';
    }

    public function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

I think code is required to conditionally load the `$output` so that when walking the taxonomy displays the right HTML for:

Categories:

```
<input value="85" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-85">
```

Taxonomy:

```
<input value="10" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[city][]" id="in-city-10">
```

I am a bit lost, thanks!